# Merging CAD and .mdb table into a feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, merge, ms-access, cad

I have cad file (.dwg) which contains the geometry and the attributes are in the tables of access (.mdb) database. The common FIELD in both of them is "HANDLE".

**How do I convert these into a geodatabase taking the geometry from the CAD and the attributes from the .mdb?**

I have tried first by converting the cad into feature class and then JOIN it with the mdb tables, but the fields are getting repeated.
How to update or copy the attributes from the tables into the geodatabase?

Answer (score 1):

This is *normal* behaviour for a Join - ALL fields are returned from both the feature class and the joined table.

[image]

You can now export that joined dataset to a new feature class
In ArcMap from the Right-Click context menu:
[image]

Or using the ArcToolbox tool [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm).

With this new feature class created, you can now use the [Delete Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-field.htm) tool to remove any uneeded repeated fields.  (Please note that Delete Field modifies the input feature class, it **does not** create a new output!)
[image]

End result after the **Delete Field**.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Midavalo for the detailed answer. 
i am familiar with this process, i have tried it before, i want to know whether if there is any other way of doing the work in fewer steps, any other way other than using the JOIN?